# What is the difference between using `root /dir/name` and `alias /dir/name` in nginx?

Tags: website, webserver, nginx, httpd

It seems like *root* and *alias* do the same things by definition, but for some reason when I use *root*, I get a 404, but it works fine when I use *alias*. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, this is how they differ.

```
location /i/ {
  alias /stuff/;
}
```

And `example.com/i/top.gif` will display `/stuff/top.git` notice the lack of the `/i/`, which the `root` directive includes.